# Как при перемещении файлов сделать паузу?

Tags: java, файлы

У меня есть 30 файлов размером по 1Гбайт. Из одного места их нужно перенести в другое параллельно.

Грубо говоря, работает так:

```
String[] files = new String[] {"file1.cat", "file2.cat"...}

for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Files.move(files[i], "target" + i);
    }).start();
}
```

Как мне поставить перемещение на паузу? Самому реализовывать перемещение через stream'ы?

Comment: О какой паузе речь? Остановить перемещение файла и позже продолжить?

Comment: А какая может быть еще пауза? Я подразумевал приостановить перемещение и продолжить, а не заново начинать после завершения паузы.

Comment: что значить перемещение? копирование? или *перемещение*?

Comment: Под перемещением я подразумеваю метод `Files.move()`, он есть в куске кода примера. А работает он, видимо, посредством копирования и удаления.

Comment: @Ep1demic Никогда не решал такую задачу, но похоже, что java не предоставляет удобный механизм для паузы процесса копирования. Советую реализовать копирование (затем удаления старого файла) через FileChannel, он хорошо для этого подходит. Там можно лекго остановить процесс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так. Пока посмотрю, что со скоростью произойдет.

```
public class FileMove {
    private static boolean globalPause = false;

    /**
     * Снять/установить общую паузу
     * @param type true установить, false снять
     */
    public static void setGlobalPause(boolean type) {
        globalPause = type;
    }

    /**
     * Перемещение файла
     * @param from откуда
     * @param to куда
     * @throws IOException ошибка копирования
     * @throws InterruptedException ошибка паузы
     */
    public static void copy(File from, File to) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if(to.exists()) {
            to.delete();
        }

        FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(from);
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(to);

        FileChannel inChannel = inFile.getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = outFile.getChannel();

        long bufferSize = 8 * 1024;
        long pos = 0;
        long count;
        long size = inChannel.size();
        while (pos < size) {
            if(globalPause) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                continue;
            }

            count = size - pos > bufferSize ? bufferSize : size - pos;
            pos += inChannel.transferTo(pos, count, outChannel);
        }

        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
    }

    /**
     * Перемещение файла
     * @param from откуда
     * @param to куда
     * @throws IOException ошибка копирования
     * @throws InterruptedException ошибка паузы
     */
    public static void move(File from, File to) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        copy(from, to);
        from.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Обновил, спасибо. А еще какой смысл от volatile, если переменная статична?

Comment: Советую более детально приглядеться к записям http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0064.html